# Why does coregraphics support PDF and why is the format so pivotal to Apple?

Tags: core-graphics

There are so many formats that intuitively are more bound to graphics: it could be vector graphics format such as SVG, various PNG, JPEG formats etc. Why PDF of them all has a dedicated library?

Note: this question is NOT opinion-based. I'm interested in the very reason for why PDF has such a central point in xOS. Give it a day to see.

Comment: @WilShipley ^^^

Answer (score 15):

*My bonafides: I licensed my PDF viewer to Apple for Rhapsody and then the PDF library I wrote in Objective-C to Apple as the basis of CoreGraphics. I’ve written code for NeXT systems since 1988, and worked as a contractor for NeXT and Apple many times.*

As Rob says, NeXTstep used Display Postscript (“DPS”), under license from Adobe. When Apple switched from “Classic” Mac OS to OS X, they absolutely  didn’t want to keep paying Adobe the per-seat license for DPS each Mac it sold – it had been years since they’d agreed to pay a per-seat license to anyone for the Mac.

And, at the same time, DPS didn’t reflect modern graphics trends. It was a Turing-complete language and ran in its own process, and client apps would have to send inter-process messages to it, which meant expensive context switches and no direct sharing of buffers. (Also it broke down isolation between client processes.)

So the graphics team (led then by Peter Graffagnino) needed to replace DPS, but also not break all the existing NeXTstep apps. As it happened an engineer at Adobe (I believe it was originally Sam Streeper) had written a graphics language that was MUCH simpler than PostScript and wasn’t Turing complete, but still had most of the drawing conventions of PostScript. (Display PostScript was superset of PostScript, so any PostScript program runs in DPS.)

PDF was originally designed for PostScript-driven printers, because lots of PostScript programs (aka “print jobs”) ended up slurping down memory and processor time and often were just too big to work on any individual printer (RAM was expensive back then). Converting PostScript files to PDF made them process far more easily, and since PDF doesn’t have control flow you couldn’t, say, send the printer into an infinite loop. (Adobe processed PDF with a PostScript program they’d send to the printer as well.)

PDF was also an open standard, so with Apple writing their own implementation they didn’t have to pay Adobe anything to use it. PDF was fast and simple and free and had the exact same model because it was designed to run on PostScript printers.

So: Apple had to switch to a new graphics language for Mac OS X (née NeXTstep), and wanted one with the same semantics and Display PostScript so all their existing apps largely still worked.

So first they wrote the functional calls to CoreGraphics, implementing all the conventions of PostScript / PDF (eg: how clip paths work, how paths are filled if they self-overlap, resolution-independence, the state stack, etc). They rewrote all the existing high-level graphics functions (eg, NSRectFill()) so they were on top of CoreGraphics, so 99% of existing NeXTstep programs could switch from DPS to CG without modification. (By the late 1990s most NeXTstep programmers had realized dipping into DPS and trying to create effects by writing PostScript was pretty much always a bad idea, so we used the high-level calls.)

But the final missing piece was giving programs a format they could read and write to disk. In NeXTstep days we used both PostScript and Encapsulated PostScript, but the former was Right Out now. PDF was a natural fit (for the reasons outlined above) so they added reading and writing of PDF files.

Postscript (pun intended): The PDF code in CoreGraphics today is not what I licensed Apple — they used my code as more of a “working reference” and came up with their own APIs, since CoreGraphics couldn’t use Objective-C and my API was never really intended to be used by general programs.

Answer (score 3):

The drawing model utilized by Quartz 2D is based on PDF specification.

It is widely stated that Quartz "uses PDF internally" (notably by Apple in their 2000 Macworld presentation and Quartz's early developer documentation), ... Quartz's internal imaging model correlates well with the PDF object graph, making it easy to output PDF to multiple devices.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(graphics_layer)#Use_of_PDF

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Continuing Mahal Tertin's points, focusing on the drawing side, which isn't really PDF-centric but the history is interesting anyway (I'll get to the file format side below).

Quartz was developed before 1999, and was a fairly natural continuation of NeXT's use of Display Postscript and QuickDraw, which conceptually goes back to the Lisa and was used extensively on pre-OS X Macs.

SVG might have been a reasonable base, but work on it didn't even start until 1999. It was never in a position to the basis for OS X drawing. Even if it had come out a couple of years earlier, it would still have been an untested experimental format vs a established format that Apple already had extensive code and experience for.

When iOS came along, it inherited Core Graphics, which made development dramatically easier for OS X developers. Converting everything to an SVG DOM or the like would have made iOS much harder to migrate to. (I had complex custom views on OS X that I ported verbatim to iOS with the addition of one flip translation and a hacky `#define` to replace `NSColor` with `UIColor`.) It also made developing iOS much easier in the first place since Apple could reuse substantial existing code. Why replace the entire drawing system with another format? To what purpose?

Quartz/PDF/Postscript all have the concept of independent objects/layers that are composited together, and has lots of support for text and lines. This makes a lot of sense when you're building a windowing system and want to easily drag a window along the screen, overlapping other windows, and minimizing computation. PNG and JPEG are built to compress single, static images. They don't make any sense for this use. JPEG in particular would be a horrible way to try to manage a windowing system full of crisp, straight lines and text, exactly the things that JPEG hates.

So that's the drawing side (which isn't really PDF-centric anyway, but it answers why SVG DOM isn't the heart of Core Graphics), but why does PDF get its own framework and not PNG?

As a graphics format, PNG *does* get a lot of support in iOS (as opposed to OS X). iOS is highly optimized to display PNG and converting images to and from PNG is very easy in iOS. There really isn't a need for a `PNGKit`. What would it do beyond what's built into UIKit, where PNG and JPEG are given their own special handling right in `UIImage` (handling PDF doesn't get)?

PDFKit exists because PDF is complicated, and it addresses printing problems that the other formats don't (things like handling multiple pages; when was the last time someone mailed you an SVG Print document?) While it may seem that it's getting a lot of special support by getting its own framework, PDFKit isn't really very good and doesn't support a lot of more complicated PDF features. So while there is a long history of PDF inside of Core Graphics, PDF as a file format is actually pretty poorly supported by Apple IMO. (Compare PSPDFKit, which much more powerful, and a necessary addition for almost any app that uses PDF in a non-trivial way.)